# My "let" term is inside a button but I cant make it accesable to outside the button

Tags: swift

I am making a "guess the number" app but I am facing problems while trying to get a let term to be accessible outside of a button here is my code and I hope you can fix it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var TextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield2: UITextField!

    @IBAction func generate(_ sender: Any) {
        let number2 = Int.random(in: 0...100)
    }

    let number2 = generate(self.number2)

    func tryrepeat() {

        let number5 = Int.random(in: 5...10)
        let number6 = Int.random(in: 5...10)

        if number2 > 90  {
            let number3 = number2 - number5
            let number4 = 0
            label3.isHidden = false
            label3.text = "your number is in-between \(number3) and \(number4) ."
        }
        if number2 < 10 {
            let number3 = 0
            let number4 = number2 + number6
            label3.isHidden = false
            label3.text = "your number is in-between \(number3) and \(number4) ."
        } else {
            let number3 = number2 - number5
            let number4 = number2 + number6
            label3.isHidden = false
            label3.text = "your number is in-between \(number3) and \(number4) ."
        }
    }


    @IBAction func clues(_ sender: Any) {
        tryrepeat()
    }

    @IBAction func check(_ sender: Any) {
    let number1 = Int(TextField.text!)

    Label1.isHidden = false
    label2.isHidden = false
    if number1 == number2 as Int? {
        Label1.text = "Well Done! You are a amazing guesser...or your just lucky..."
        label2.isHidden = true
    } else {
        Label1.text = "Sorry...Your number was too low or too high."
    }
    if number1! < number2 {
        label2.text = "Your number was too low!"
    }
    if number1! > number2 {
        label2.text = "Your number was too high!"
    }
        if (((TextField.text)?.isEmpty ?? nil)!) {
            Alert.showBasic(title: "TextBox Is Empty", msg: "The TextBox is empty please try agin", vc: self)

        }
    }
}
```

the error I am getting in

```
let number2 = generate(self.number2)
```

this part is

> "Value of type '(ViewController) -> () -> ViewController' has no member 'number2'"
>   Thanks and hope you can help!

Comment: in this line `let number2 = generate(self.number2)`, you are declaring `number2`and using it  before even it is declared

Comment: `self` is for property members, you are trying to refer a local variable (that you are creating on the same line!)

Comment: Probably you meant `self.label2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared number2 inside `func generate(_ sender: Any)` , so it can only be accessed within the function scope. If you want other functions to access it, declare the variable inside Class.

```
var number2 : Int = 0
@IBAction func generate(_ sender: Any) {
    number2 = Int.random(in: 0...100)
}
```

Also remove this line: `let number2 = generate(self.number2)`

Comment: but why will we send number2 as a parameter for this method, `(_ sender: Any)` is for the id of button instance, so better send `0` not a Int variable.

Comment: @Shabbir Its a button action. generate function will get called on the tap of the button. Once user tap the button, `number2 = 89 // any random number` . And thats what he needs.

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com